# Rendering buttons on top of imageview without button background

Tags: android

Can someone please let me know how to add a button on top of an image view . I am attaching a sample[image]

Comment: use a relative layout and just stack the images. Use an icon file with a transparent background

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple solutions.

On solution can be, using FrameLayout as root view. Then using an ImageView for the background image and finally a linear layout for holding the icons. Inside the LinearLayout, you will add the icons with transparent background.

Example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```